# Error code 8 in android speech recognition on Nexus 7 tablet

Tags: android, android-intent, speech-recognition

I am trying to build an android app and it is working fine on Samsung galaxy S3 even in stress testing , like pressing microphone image button repeatedly

But I am having Error8 on my nexus7 tablet in the same stress testing microphone like pressing repeatedly ,after that app needs to be restarted in order to work properly
For normal usage it is working fine in nexus7 too.

Below code is recognition class;

```
public class MyRecognitionListener implements RecognitionListener
```

This is how i call speech recognition;

```
Intent recognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, langParam);
        //recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
        recognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS,10);

        try {
            recognizer.startListening(recognizerIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            recognizer.stopListening();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would appreciate any help or clue

Best Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error ERROR\_RECOGNIZER\_BUSY with offline speech recognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866239/error-error-recognizer-busy-with-offline-speech-recognition)

Answer (score 1):

Error 8 is ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY which may occur when the recognizer has too many requests or some other weird issue.

Here's some pseudocode that should work. I'm not too sure of your implementation, but if you do some overriding:

```
onError(int e) {
  if(e == 8) {
    mRecognitionListener.cancel();
    mRecognitionListener.startListening();
  }
}
```